# levenshtein distance for indexed dictionary

Tags: javascript, levenshtein-distance

I'm currently having trouble with a fuzzy string matcher I've implemented. I want to be able to quickly determine, in less than one second or so, which phrases from a list of 10,000 phrases have an edit distance of 2 or less to any one of 200,000 phrases in a dictionary, using Javascript. The phrases average about 15 characters each. I don't care how many matches there are, or even what the match is, just whether there is a match or not. I can do any indexing before hand on the words in the dictionary that I would like, but none on the other words.

My main approach has been to use a BK tree. It generally takes about 130-140 seconds to classify all 10,000 words, so about two orders of magnitude lower than what I'm hoping for. Is it realistic to be able to classify the phrases that quickly in Javascript? If so what techniques should I be using, is there a quicker method than BK trees that is used for problems like this?

Comment: Have you tried doing it in a WebWorker?

Comment: No, I would like to get the results very quickly if possible. I am doing this in node.js.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise my Levenshtein implementation as it is the fastest I've ever seen.

```
var levenshtein = (function() {
    var row2 = [];
    return function(s1, s2) {
        if (s1 === s2) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            var s1_len = s1.length, s2_len = s2.length;
            if (s1_len && s2_len) {
                var i1 = 0, i2 = 0, a, b, c, c2, row = row2;
                while (i1 < s1_len)
                    row[i1] = ++i1;
                while (i2 < s2_len) {
                    c2 = s2.charCodeAt(i2);
                    a = i2;
                    ++i2;
                    b = i2;
                    for (i1 = 0; i1 < s1_len; ++i1) {
                        c = a + (s1.charCodeAt(i1) === c2 ? 0 : 1);
                        a = row[i1];
                        b = b < a ? (b < c ? b + 1 : c) : (a < c ? a + 1 : c);
                        row[i1] = b;
                    }
                }
                return b;
            } else {
                return s1_len + s2_len;
            }
        }
    };
})();
```